# Storm door catch too close to door knob

Tags: storm-door

From the image you can see the storm door latch is too close to the door knob causing you to scratch your hand when you try and open it. There are about three layers of support behind that catch, too.

The storm door fits well where it is, and doesn't look out of the ordinary, so I don't know what to do about the catch.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider replacing that door catch with one of this style. It would be a lot less traumatic to the knuckles when you use the regular door knob.

[image]

Alternatively you could consider a change of the regular door knob to an exterior lever style unit. These have additional benefit in that they can be opened by means other then a free hand which can be useful when you come in with two bags of groceries.

[image]

Comment: The lever handle is a good option but these are new door knobs in the first place. I was really hoping to have someone come up with an alternative, or fix, for the catch but your idea is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Raise the catch and the lock on the door to about 42", about the height of the deadbolt.

Comment: It never occurred to me that this is a simple hole through the door and I'd only need to drill a new one. Is it that simple? I assume I can find some covers to plug the old hole with?

Comment: Bit nasty to plug a door hole... if you were desperate, you could invert the deadbolt and the knob with relatively little work. Still wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate After further review, I realized that moving the door handle only moves the problem from the knob to the lock. We would still scrape our hand on the catch so this problem still isn't solved.